# Reactで作成したSPAをNginxでホスティングする時のdefault.confの設定を教えてください。

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Reactで作成したSPAをNginxでホスティングしたいです。
その際に、パスの設定を/login/hoge, /login/fugaのように/login/から始まるパスにアクセスした場合にReactのSPAにルーティングするように設定したいです。
現在以下のように設定を行ったのですが、うまくいきません。

default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /login/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir /var/www \
mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/login \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install vim less -y
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/login　# Nginxコンテナの/usr/share/nginx/html/loginにReactSPAのindex.htmlが配置されます
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

ReactSPAのパスの設定

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ReactNotifications />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login/common" element={<CommonLogin />} />
          <Route path="/login/fuga" element={<FugaLogin />} />
          <Route path="/login/piyo" element={<PiyoLogin />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

上記の設定を行ったうえで、Nginxコンテナを立ち上げて`http://localhost:8080/login/common`にアクセスすると、以下のスクショのように「ページに到達できません」と出て、アドレスバーのポート番号がなくなってしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
開発者ツールのネットワークを見るとレスポンスが返ってきていないようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どのように設定すれば/login/で始まるパスにアクセスしたときにReactSPAにアクセスすることができるでしょうか？